# driver.close() method is not working in Selenium WebDriver on Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a simple program in Eclipse using JUnit annotation.

`diver.close()` is not closing my Firefox browser after the tests. It works fine with Chrome. Code snippet is here.

```
public class FireFox1 {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/chapter4");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExamples() {
        WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("nextBid"));
        element.sendKeys("100");     

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the intention of using `driver.close()` instead of `driver.quit()`?

Comment: Also the same code with Firefox and Junit ran without any issue and closed the browser.

Comment: Hey Saifur, It works fine with driver.quit() here but I want to know why it is not working with close() method.

Comment: Hey Chandan, I am using latest version of firefox 38.0.5. Does this the cause for it??

Comment: my config - selenium 2.45, firefox 38.05 on mac osx.

Comment: Could be. In fact, firefox 38 is not officially supported by Selenium 2.45. So, we can expect some issues with latest version

Answer (score 5):

sometimes while on repeated usages,we'll facing problems with `driver.close()`.
Anyways `driver.quit()` will rectify your problem.

Generally `driver.close()` closes the browser(the instance of driver is still intact) and `driver.quit()` is to kill the webdriver instance. As anyhow you are using here for only one page,then you can go with `driver.quit()`.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of problems does driver.close() have?

Answer (score 3):

Better use `driver.quit()` method. It closes the browser, but due to some unknown issues it throws `NullPointerException`. Just catch it..

```
try{
    driver.quit();
   }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Nothing to do with it");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you have started 5 browsers(classes) parallely using grid:**

driver.close - Used for close the current browser( where execution going on)

driver.quit  - Used for close all the browsers started by the current execution.

You can use any one of this..

May be browser compatiblity issue, try to downgrade the FF let we see...

Answer (score 0):

Use latest GeckoDriver.exe (17) with Latest FireFox (54.0);
It works fine for me. I had the same problem before.

This problem that you are facing is completely a compatibility problem between driver & Browser version.

driver.close(); should have work without problem if you use above versions. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the problem in Firefox driver.close() works in Firefox only with internet connection but in case of Chrome it  works without internet connection.

Comment: How do you know that Firefox requires an active connection but Chrome doesn't? Do you have any references you can link to which can substantiate what you saying?